# Creation of array with results of different xPath::query(s). Improvement?

Tags: php, arrays, xpath

I don't actually have a problem, however, I am looking to improve my source code. I have three different queries whose results should be combined in an array. An example of the array:

```
array(
    array(
        'q0-result' => '...',
        'q1-result' => '...',
        'q2-result' => '...'
    ),
    array(
        'q0-result' => '...',
        'q1-result' => '...',
        'q2-result' => '...'
    )
);
```

So now I have the following source code, however, I do not like the usage of $idx and how the array is being built. Do you have suggestions to improve the following source code?:

```
$data = array();
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.example.com'));
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

$idx = 0;
foreach($xpath->query('query0') as $element) {
    $data[$idx]['q0-result'] = $element->nodeValue;
}

$idx = 0;
foreach($xpath->query('query1') as $element) {
    $data[$idx]['q1-result'] = $element->nodeValue;
}

$idx = 0;
foreach($xpath->query('query2') as $element) {
    $data[$idx]['q2-result'] = $element->nodeValue;
}

var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If i understood) Do it:

```
 foreach($xpath->query('query0') as $element)
   $data['q0-result'][] = $element->nodeValue;

 foreach($xpath->query('query1') as $element) 
  $data['q1-result'][] = $element->nodeValue;

 foreach($xpath->query('query2') as $element) 
  $data['q2-result'][] = $element->nodeValue;

 // below chunking  in your format
 /*
  array(
    array(
     'q0-result' => '...',
     'q1-result' => '...',
     'q2-result' => '...'
  ),
  array(
    'q0-result' => '...',
    'q1-result' => '...',
    . ......
 */

 $out = array();

 $row0=array_shift($data['q0-result']);
 $row1=array_shift($data['q1-result']);
 $row2=array_shift($data['q2-result']);

 while($row0 || $row1 || $row2){

  $row0 = !empty($row0)? $row0 : null;
  $row1 = !empty($row1)? $row1 : null;
  $row2 = !empty($row2)? $row2 : null;

  $out[] = array('q0-result'=>$row0,'q1-result'=>$row1,'q2-result'=>$row2 );

  $row0=array_shift($data['q0-result']);
  $row1=array_shift($data['q1-result']);
  $row2=array_shift($data['q2-result']);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. Will take a closer look at array_shift() to understand it.

Comment: Changed it to `$row0 = (!empty($data['q0-result'])) ? array_shift($data['q0-result']) : null;` to avoid errors in case one of the queries doesn't return a result.

Comment: yes. i wrote checking on empty: `$row0 = !empty($row0)? $row0 : null;`. You can change how is needing.